# How can I process data from Kafka with PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, data-processing

I want to process logs data from Kafka streaming to PySpark and save to Parquet files, but I don't know how to input the data to Spark. Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is on high level. You need to use spark-streaming and need to have some basic understanding of messaging systems like Kafka.

The application that sends data into Kafka (or any messaging system) is called "producer" and the application that receives data from Kafka is called as "consumer". When producer sends data, it will send data to a specific "topic". Multiple producers can send data to Kafka layer under different topics.

You basically need to create a consumer application. To do that, first you need to identify the topic you are going to consume data from.

You can find many sample programs online. Following page can help you to build your first application

https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2017/01/getting-started-with-spark-streaming-with-python-and-kafka/